# Output dropdown results into Woocommerce Order details

Tags: plugins, array, dropdown, select

How do I correctly get the data from a drop down (select) output into the Woocommerce Order Details section of the admin?

When I do this, I get an output for all my text box questions, but nothing for the select (dropdown).

```
$this->address_formats = apply_filters('woocommerce_localisation_address_formats',  array(
        'default' => "{question}\n"

function get_address_fields( $country, $type = 'billing_' ) {
$locale     = $this->get_country_locale();

$fields = array(    
    'question' => array(
    'label'       => __('Question?', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => yes,
    'clear'       => yes,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'option'     => array(
        'yes' => __('yes', 'woocommerce' ),
        'no' => __('no', 'woocommerce' )
)),

);
```

When I do this I do not get any data output in the Order details of Woocommerce

```
$options[] = array(
    'question' => array(
        'label'       => __('Question?', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => yes,
        'clear'       => yes,
        'type'        => 'select',
        'options' => $test_array
    )));


$test_array = array(
        'no' => __('yes', 'woocommerce' ),
        'yes' => __('no', 'woocommerce' )
```

);

Comment: I think we need a little bit more context than this. Where do you put this code? What do you want specifically? Where are you calling this drop down? How is the data saved (did you check the db?).

Comment: The code is in the class-wc_countries.php  I am new to php so I am not sure what my next step is.

Comment: Do you want to add an extra field to the checkout page with a drop-down?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the WooCommerce docs here: [Tutorial – Customising checkout fields using actions and filters](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

your code would look something like this:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Question?'),
    'placeholder'       => __('Enter something'),
    'options'           => array(
        'Yes' => __('Yes', 'woocommerce' ),
        'No' => __('No', 'woocommerce' )
    )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));
}
```

though the input also needs processing to be displayed in the WC admin. If you have little experience with PHP, it's not that easy though. You could take a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/claudiosmweb/woocommerce-extra-checkout-fields-for-brazil) for inspiration.